# Replace classname with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

How can i find elements with `flag-view-v3` `class name` ,then find neighbor class (ex. `flag-CoteD'Ivoire`) and remove all ' symbols from this `class name`

```
.flag-Chile {background: url('../images/ChileFlag.png');}
.flag-Chinese'Taipei {...}
.flag-Colombia {...}
.flag-Costa'Rica {...}
.flag-CoteD'Ivoire {...}
.flag-Dominican'Republic...{}

<div class="flag-view-v3 flag-Dominican'Republic"></div>
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried and where are the errors

Comment: I have no ideas how to get neighbor class of classname or find all classes with flag-* prefix

Comment: You can use document.getElementByClassName and then access all classes with getAttribute('class') you can access all classes of it.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp
Let me know if you need an example.

Comment: @AroTonoyan If you don't even know how to find elements with a given class name, you should first think about learning the basics of JS. You will not understand the code for the answer

Comment: Why do you want to remote the `'`, and why not add the class correctly in the first place, and why do your css selectors have the `'` but you want to remove it from the element's class?

Comment: @DominicTobias classnames come from websocket ,its not static classnames

Comment: @Weedoze I know syntax's of native js not so good , usual i use jquery for this tasks , but now i use angularjs1.6 without jquery jqlite , i need to find neighbor element of static classname , or find classname with flag- prefix

Comment: @AroTonoyan Ok then go on google and look for tutorials. Don't come here saying *I can't do this, do it for me please even if I don't understand the answer*. @K D already gave you some hints. Use this to try something and update your question with your code

Comment: @Weedoze , problem about SYNTAX of native JavaScript ,
if you now answer of question ,but didnt want help me , please ignore my question

Comment: @AroTonoyan I will help you. Just provide some code that you tried. After that I will explain you what is not working and why then provide you a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var div = document.querySelectorAll('.flag-view-v3');

for(var i=0;i<div.length;i++){
    div[i].className = div[i].className.replace("'","");
}
```

Comment: Thanks (Y) (Y) (Y)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this easily with jQuery just include the jQuery file :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And then use this code to do what you are trying to do :

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $(".flag-view-v3").siblings(".flag-CoteD'Ivoire");
    });
</script>
```

This is how you can access the siblings, now i don't know what kind of symbols you want to remove. If you can post your code i might help you fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.flag-view-v3')
  .forEach(el => (el.className = el.className.replace("'", '')));
```

Note that [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) on a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) isn't supported on old browsers but there are alternative ways to iterate over them if you need to.